# run two javascriptscript files with same function names

Tags: javascript

I have 2 javascript files which needs to run when a specific event occurs.

```
<object>
  <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
  <param name="width" value="550" />
  <param name="height" value="320" />
 --------------------------------
 --------------------------------
 -------------------------------- 
  <param name="templateLoadHandler" value="BCL.funcName">
  <param name="includeAPI" value="true">
</object>
```

Once uses a namespace and has some functions attached to it.

```
Var BCL = {};
BCL.funcName = function (){

}
```

Another does not use a name space but has the same functions in it. This is a very generic script file and I do not want to modify it.

```
funcName = function (){

}
```

I want both the scripts to run on a specific event. How do I get both the functions to run?

EDIT: 
The first function BCL.funcName is getting called by the flash param. So what is happening is when I call the generic function, funcName within the BCL.funcName, The BCL.funcName does not execute at all.

Comment: You need to post the actual code that's not working.

Comment: I wish I could but unfortunately its in Dev environment and cant take it to the public domain until I get this issue resolved.

Comment: Well the problem is that what your wrote in your edit is not possible if the code really is exactly as you describe. Thus, there must either be a syntax error you're not noticing, or something else that's causing the weird behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to call all the functions in this manner:

```
BCL.funcName(){
  funcName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems kind of trivial, unless I'm missing something.

Just call both functions sequentially:

```
BCL.funcName();
funcName();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run both of them in an anonymous function,
for example, for a "onclick" do this:

```
document.getElementById(“buttonname”).onclick= function() {
   BCL.funcName();
   funcname();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, for ex:

```
window.onload=init; 
function init(){
  BCL.funcName();
  funcName();
}
```

?
or:

```
window.onload=function(){
  BCL.funcName();
  funcName();
}
```